# Kivy: How can I connect TextInput in .KV file to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to create a simple login page for this app using Kivy.

I'm new to this, and I'm wondering how I can connect the Email TextInput to a variable (`email_catch`) in my python code, similar to a normal .get() function.

Python Code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty



class Login_Window(Screen):


    def verify(self):
        email_catch = self.root.ids.email.text
        print(email_catch)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login_Window()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

.KV File

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<Login_Window>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: 'Email'
            TextInput:
                multiline: False
                id: email

        Button:
            text: 'Log In'
            on_press: root.verify()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling `root` in `verify` method of `Login_Window` class (where it (`root`) hasn't been defined yet) and not in the `build` method of the `App` class you are supposed to get an `AttributeError` .

In order to access an `id` within that class you should use `self.ids`. So the change you need:

```py
    def verify(self):
        email_catch = self.ids.email.text
        print(email_catch)
```

Comment: I made that change but it still gives me the same Attribute Error.
What do you mean by ```verify``` not being defined in the ```Login_Window``` class? 
I made sure to indent it correctly inside of the class.

Comment: What's the name of your `.kv` file ? Make sure (in this case) this is `my.kv` (as your app's subclass is `MyApp`) .

Comment: Yes the name of the ```.kv``` file is not the issue. It connects to that.

Comment: With this modification your posted code works as expected for me and also is supposed to work for you unless there are some other issues. Please check that thoroughly and update any information if needed.